# кнопка не реагирует на нажатие после анимации

Tags: android, android-animation, android-button

Имеется кнопка и анимация. При нажатии на кнопку сама кнопка перемещается в  `android:toYDelta="-200"`и остаётся там, но не реагирует на нажатия. На нажатие реагирует только первоначальное место кнопки.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Потому что данная анимация меняет не реальное свойство объекта, а его представление. Соответственно положение у объекта тоже самое что и первоначальное. Для того чтобы у объекта менялись свойства посмотрите что такое view property animation. 
У вас будет что-то похожее:

```
ObjectAnimator objectAnimator= ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(mContent_container, "translationX", startX, endX);
objectAnimator.setDuration(1000);
objectAnimator.start();
```