# Не нажимается ImageButton после анимации

Tags: java, android, массивы, анимация, android-animation

Вем привет. Разрабатываю игру пазл на подобие пятнашек. Суть проблемы такова. Имеются кнопки `(ImageButton)` в коллекции `ArrayList mButtons` и на каждую повешан свой слушатель, у слушателя прописываю анимирование кнопки. При нажатии на кнопку анимация срабатывает хорошо, НО!!! если идти назад к той кнопке которую мы передвинули она не нажимается! Как буд то поверх нее еще наложилась текстура! Другие кнопки нажимаются. Перепробовал все что можно:

```
v.getAnimation().reset();
v.getAnimation().cancel();
v.clearAnimation();
v.setAnimation(null);
v.getAnimation().setAnimationListener(null);
```

не помогло! Если есть советы и вы сталкивались с той же проблемой прошу ответить!

Картинка для нагядности:

[image: puzzle]

Нужная часть кода, чтобы было понятнее:

```
public class TouchButtonAction implements View.OnClickListener {
private GameController mController;
private List<ImageButton> mButtons;
private List<GridLayout.LayoutParams> mParams;
private final Animation myAnimA;
private volatile  boolean isAnimAFinish = true;

public TouchButtonAction(Context context, GameController controller, List<ImageButton> buttons, List<GridLayout.LayoutParams> params) {
    this.mParams = params;
    this.mButtons = buttons;
    this.mController = controller;
    this.myAnimA = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, R.anim.bounce_swap);
    final ButtonBounceInterpolator mInterpolatorA = new ButtonBounceInterpolator(0.07, 20);
    this.myAnimA.setInterpolator(mInterpolatorA);
    //        this.myAnimA.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
     //            @Override
      //            public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
      //                isAnimAFinish = false;
    ////                animation.setFillAfter(false);
    ////                animation.reset();
     //
    //            }
    //
     //            @Override
    //            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
   ////                animation.reset();
   //                animation.cancel();
   //                isAnimAFinish = true;
   ////                synchronized (this){
   //
   ////                }
   //            }
   //
   //            @Override
   //            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
   //
   //            }
   //        });

@Override
public void onClick(final View v) {
    int a = mButtons.indexOf((ImageButton) v);

    int b = 0;
    for (ImageButton button : mButtons) {
        if (!button.isEnabled()) {
            b = mButtons.indexOf(button);
        }
    }

    if (тут проверка логики) {
        SoundPlay.playSoundPool(SoundPlay.TOUCH);

            if (isAnimAFinish){
   //                    v.post(new Runnable() {
   //                        @Override
   //                        public void run() {
   //                            synchronized (this){
                            v.startAnimation(myAnimA);
                            isAnimAFinish = false;
   //                            }
   //
   //                        }
   //                    });
            }
            if (v.getAnimation() != null){
                if (v.getAnimation().hasEnded()){
                    Log.d("LOGGG", "hasEnded Anim");
                    v.getAnimation().reset();
                    v.getAnimation().cancel();
                    v.clearAnimation();
                    v.setAnimation(null);
                    v.getAnimation().setAnimationListener(null);
                    isAnimAFinish = true;

                }
            }


        Collections.swap(mButtons, a, b);
        mController.getGridLayout().removeAllViewsInLayout();
        mController.getGridLayout().removeAllViews();
        for (int i = 0; i < mButtons.size(); i++) { // i < 12
            ImageButton button = mButtons.get(i);
            mController.getGridLayout().addView(button, mParams.get(i));
        }

        mController.getGridLayout().invalidate();
    } else {
        SoundPlay.playSoundPool(SoundPlay.TOUCH_BANG);
    }
    mController.checkSolution(mButtons);
}
```

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/604733/177345

Comment: Спасибо за ссылку разобарлся.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Оказывается, надо было использовать не AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(), а совсем другие классы которые позволяют манипулировать объектами, например такие как виджеты.

Пример анимации прыгающей кнопки:

```
AnimatorSet as = new AnimatorSet();
float y = view.getTranslationY(), distance = 20F;
as.playSequentially(
   ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(view, "translationY", y - distance), // анимация 1
   ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(view, "translationY", y), // анимация 2
   ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(view, "translationY", y - (distance / 2)), // анимация 3
   ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(view, "translationY", y)); // анимация 4
as.setDuration(600);
as.start();
```

И анимация вашего виджета начинает прыгать. Надеюсь вам это помогло как и мне.